# How to check network connection in a mobile app, using Vue3

Tags: web-worker, vuejs3

I am writing a PWA using vue3, where I need to notify when the user goes offline. I am  trying to use webworkerto listen to the online/offline.

```
const worker = new Worker('./longSleepWorker.js', { type: 'module' });

const send = message => worker.postMessage({
  message
})

export default {
  worker,
  send
}
Is this the correct approach or should I use
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "https://www.kirupa.com/blank.png";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
 
    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, true);
    xhr.send();
     
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
 
    function processRequest(e) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
          alert("connection exists!");
        } else {
          alert("connection doesn't exist!");
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to check for network status by querying [`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine#Examples).

> To see changes in the network state, use `addEventListener` to listen for the events on `window.online` and `window.offline`, as in the following example:

```js
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {
  console.log('offline');
});

window.addEventListener('online', function(e) {
  console.log('online');
});
```

[Browser supports are good](https://caniuse.com/online-status) (98.27% supported, at the time of writing).